# how to capture packets in pcap, and skip ethernet header

Tags: c, tcp, wireshark, libpcap, tcpdump

I am using 
`fp = pcap_open_dead(DLT_EN10MB,65535);`
 to capture frames in pcap format. But what `fp = pcap_open_dead(**DLT_XXX** )`
 should I use **if I want to skip the ethernet header**. My module is working on layer 3 , so I want to capture packets starting from layer 3.

```
fp = pcap_open_dead(DLT_EN10MB,65535);
if (NULL == fp)
{
    FPA_ERROR_PRINT("unable to open the dead interface \n");
    return 1;
```

Any help will on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ethernet header is always 14byte long, so you can advance the pointer 14 positions to get it skipped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using  `fp = pcap_open_dead(DLT_EN10MB,65535);` to capture frames in pcap format.

Presumably you mean "to write frames to a file in pcap format"; the "dead" in "pcap_open_dead" means "not live", as in "you can't capture packets from this".

(It's necessary because the `pcap_dump_open()` call doesn't take a DLT_ value and a snapshot length as a type, it takes a `pcap_t *` and gets the DLT_ value and snapshot length from there.  That's convenient if you're saving packets from a live capture you opened with `pcap_open_live()` or `pcap_create()`/`pcap_activate()`, or another capture file you opened with `pcap_open_offline()`, but it's not very convenient if the packets aren't coming from libpcap/WinPcap.)

> But what fp = pcap_open_dead(**DLT_XXX** ) should I use if I want to skip the ethernet header. My module is working on layer 3 , so I want to capture packets starting from layer 3.

If "layer 3" means "IP", so that all your packets are IPv4 or IPv6 packets, you want `DLT_RAW`.

Skipping the Ethernet header, however, is *your* job.  If whatever mechanism is supplying the captured frames is supplying frames with Ethernet headers, then *you* have to skip the Ethernet header - and discard frames where the type/length field in the Ethernet header is anything other than 0x0800 for IPv4 or 0x86dd for IPv6 - and calculate the appropriate captured length and on-the-wire length (14 bytes fewer than the captured and on-the-wire lengths of the frames with Ethernet headers; if either of those are less than or equal to 14, discard the frame), and hand those, along with a pointer to the data after the Ethernet header to `pcap_dump()`.

Comment: Thanks Harris !! It was useful

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. You need to manually skip the Ethernet header part when parsing the packet buffer.

Comment: This is a comment more than an answer

Comment: @Samer I can't post comments, need certain "reputation" level for this :) Anyway, hope it will be helpful.